# Calculating Anomaly Score for Histogram Based Outlier Score in PYOD

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

[Data](https://file.io/clrobJ)I have a problem with the calculation of the anomaly scoring using Histogram Based Outlier Score algorithm from the Pyod library of python. Algorithm seems not to calculate true scores. I'm actually new at this subject.

My data have two columns, but I'm searching anomaly only in one column named as Values. The other column is ID column. I have tried to first labelling data and then tried to calculate anomaly scores. I'm working on unsupervised data, that's why I've not labelled values.

```
from pyod.models.hbos import HBOS
acv = df['Value']
acv_v = acv.values.reshape(-1,1)
random_state = np.random.RandomState(42)


clf = HBOS(contamination=0.5,n_bins=65)
clf.fit(acv_v)
clf_pred = clf.labels_
clf_score = clf.decision_scores_
clf_score = pd.DataFrame(clf_score)
clf_pred = pd.DataFrame(clf_pred)
result = pd.merge(df,clf_pred, how='left', left_index=True,       right_index=True)
final_result = pd.merge(result, clf_score, how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
plt.hist(final_result['Value'],bins=50)
```

I'm expecting to calculate an anomaly score for every data point such as 2.64, 2.61,...,1.09,0.8...

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: I couldn't fix the issue, actually I can label the data as anomaly or not, but I would like to calculate scores, but I couldn't. That's why I'm using Median Absolute Deviation Outlier Score. @NaveenKumarNamachivayam